# Is there a symbol for arg-top-k (similar to argmax) in latex?

Tags: math-operators

$\arg\max$ is the standard symbol for $\arg$ top-1. What if I want top-$k$ for $k > 1$? $\arg\max$ is already not well-defined all the time, so I don't feel guilty for introducing another pseudo math operator coming from pre-dominantly CS literature. But it's pretty handy for situations like explaining Gumbel soft-max (or soft-Gumbel-max as some prefer).

As an example output $\top_k({x_1, \ldots, x_n},k=3)$ should produce the set of top 3 $x_i$'s.

Comment: `\arg\max` is not the best way to go anyway. Can you give an approximate representation of the desired output?

Comment: @egreg I updated the post. Let me know if it's what you want. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but it's really unclear. Can you do a sketch of the desired output and add the picture?

Comment: Maybe just `\newcommand{\argtopk}{\mathop{\mathrm{arg\,top}\,k}}`?

Comment: Did you search for your command via http://detexify.kirelabs.org ?